# Accessing Web App running on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I have an EC2 instance that is running searchkit.

I successfully started the searchkit web app and it gave me an IP address that I should be able to access via my local machine, as well as a localhost destination. But when I try to access the given IP address I get a time out.

When I use my ec2 instance to ping the IP address I get a successful connection, this makes me think that it is a permissions issue on the ec2 side. Does anyone know what permissions (which IAM role?) are needed to locally access a web app running on an EC2 instance.